# Can I stop this blue highlight from appearing?

Tags: css

I've added the angular-bootstrap pagination widget to my app. It works perfectly but if I click the Next button in quick succession, the whole widget highlights.

[image]

Is there a way to stop this highlighting?

*I'm not going to add an angular tag as I'd imagine any fix would be CSS*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is `user-select`. Use this class:

```
.noselect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

**Snippet**

```css
.noselect {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<p>You can select me.</p>
<p class="noselect">Dare to select me.</p>
```